# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "itemimages-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I used to have a one picture field and I wanted to change it to multiple pictures field:
I had

```
picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="items")
```

So I created a new model :

```
class ItemImages(models.Model):
    itemImage = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="items")
```

Afterwards, I created the viewset: (**Please note that I don't know what I'm doing**)

```
class ItemImagesViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    for_model = Item
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemImagesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
```

Then the urls turn :

```
router = ExtendedSimpleRouter()
...
(
    router.register(r'items', ItemViewSet)
          .register(r'itemimages', ItemImagesViewSet, 'items-images', parents_query_lookups=['items']) # I added this line 
          .register(r'reviews',
                    ItemReviewViewSet,
                    'items-review',
                    parents_query_lookups=['content_id'])
)
```

My serializers :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from inventory.models import Item, ItemImages
from users.api.serializers import ObjectReviewsSerializer


class ItemSerializer(ObjectReviewsSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = (
            'category', 'id', 'pictures', 'created', 'title',
            'url', 'value', 'user', 'reviews_url', 'rating', 'description'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'created', 'modified', '')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.update({
            'user': self.context['request'].user,
        })
        return super(ItemSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        more_fee = attrs.get('more_fee', None)
        less_fee = attrs.get('less_fee', None)
        if not more_fee and not less_time_fee and not self.instance:
            msg = _('You should provide either a more fee or a less  fee')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        return attrs


class ItemImagesSerializer(ObjectReviewsSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemImages
```

It gives the error stated in title when I'm requesting `/items/23`
I know I'm doing a lot of things wrongly but I fail to know what and why.
I'm new to Django Rest and Django in general and I'm playing with an existent project (trying to change one picture to many)

Complete error message:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/v1/items/23/ Could not resolve URL for
>   hyperlinked relationship using view name "itemimages-detail". You may
>   have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly
>   configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Comment: You forgot to include your serializers, the most important part of the equation.

Comment: Where do I include it ?

Comment: It should be included in your post, just edit it in. I can tell you that your error is coming from your serializer. Speaking of errors, you might also want to include the traceback (if you have one) in your question.

Comment: I added serializers, but the traceback is so long, what would you read in the traceback ?

Answer (score 2):

You register "itemimages" using "items-images" as the base name for your URLS instead of the default queryset property name, this means that a url with name "itemimages-detail" no longer exists, rather your viewset's detail url will be "items-images-detail" (see [Usage section of the DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)).

Since you also don't specify a field for the "picture" field for your serializer it'll try to use the default HyperLinkRelatedField serializer with default view_name "itemimages-detail". In your ItemSerializer you'll want to specify a field for pictures with the correct, non-default view_name:

```
pictures = serializers.HyperLinkRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    view_name='items-images-detail',
)
```